# Is there a simple way to split a NSString into an array of characters?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

Is there a simple way to split a NSString into an array of characters?  It would actually be best if the resulting type were a collection of NSString's themselves, just one character each.

Yes, I know I can do this in a loop, but I'm wondering if there is a faster way to do this with any existing methods or functions the way you can with LINQ in C#.

e.g.

```
// I have this...
 NSString * fooString = @"Hello";

// And want this...
NSArray * fooChars; // <-- Contains the NSStrings, @"H", @"e", @"l", @"l" and @"o"
```

Comment: This probably won't answer this question, but someone has [implemented LINQ's methods for `NSEnumerator` objects](https://github.com/k06a/NSEnumeratorLinq).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do something like this (if you want to use enumerators)

```
NSString *fooString = @"Hello";
NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[fooString length]]; 

[fooString enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, fooString.length)
                              options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                           usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    [characters addObject:substring];
}];
```

And if you really wanted it in an NSArray finally

```
NSArray *fooChars = [NSArray arrayWithArray:characters];
```

Comment: Thanks!  Still getting used to blocks, which is odd considering how comfortable I am with lambda and anonymous methods in C#!

Comment: Just a detail: The cast to `NSArray*` does not convert the array, it just casts the pointer, which is unnecessary in this case. If you want to create an immutable array, you can use the `arrayWithArray:` convenience method, for instance.

Comment: Or, if you want a shortcut:

```NSArray *fooChars = characters.copy;```

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to care about that some characters like emoji and others may span a longer range than just one index.

Here's a category method for NSString

```
@implementation (SplitString)

- (NSArray *)splitString
{
    NSUInteger index = 0;
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.length];

    while (index < self.length) {
        NSRange range = [self rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:index];
        NSString *substring = [self substringWithRange:range];
        [array addObject:substring];
        index = range.location + range.length;
    }

    return array;
}

@end
```

Comment: Regional indicators not joined as flags

Answer (score 0):

convert it to `NSData` the `[data bytes]` will have a C string in the encoding that you pick `[data length]` bytes long.

Comment: No, this does not give you an array of characters. It gives you an array of bytes representing whatever character encoding you used when converting the string to data. Not at all the same things being requested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *str = @"Hello";
for (int i = 0; i < [str length]; i++) {
    NSString *ch = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
    [array addObject:ch];
}
```