# NSPredicate issue with characters in filter string

Tags: xcode, nspredicate

Need some briljant mind here ;-)
Im using an NSPredicate to filter an NSArray with a UISearchBar. This works but it has one issue. For example:

```
Search: Loreal
```

In the NSArray the Loreal is a brand.name value in the Objective C example. But the exact string is:

```
"L'Oreal"
```

I would like that my NSPredicate would find this value based on the search: Loreal

It should ignore special characters..

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF.name LIKE[c] %@) OR (ANY SELF.brands.name contains[c] %@) OR (ANY SELF.brands.name contains[cd] %@) OR (ANY SELF.brands.name MATCHES[cd] %@)",searchText,searchText,searchText,searchText];
```

Comment: I _think_ this is not possible using predicates.

Comment: You cannot make NSPredicate ignore ' ?

Comment: You may construct a Regex by adding `\W*` between each letter of the searched string. You can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254031/is-there-a-simple-way-to-split-a-nsstring-into-an-array-of-characters add `@"\\W*"` in the enumerateLoop, and combine them at the end.

Comment: Use `predicateWithBlock:` or don't use a predicate and filter with `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` and `objectsAtIndexes:`.