# Create smart Searching In NSMutableArray similar to matching in XCode

Tags: swift, xcode

Im adding searching in UITableView. I want to add smart searching like used in XCode

### For example

Keyword

**Smarting**

Should match with

1. **Smart**Search**ing**
2. **Smart**Watch**ing**

**I also want to make bold to matching letters in resulting UILabel inside UITableView**

XCode used this kind of search too

I'm attaching a snapshot from XCode

[image]

How we can achieve this

Note: This is not normal searching.

Comment: Could be related: [UITableView filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738518/uitableview-filtering)

Comment: @AhmadF: Perhaps I am overlooking something, but I cannot see a solution to this specific problem in that Q&A.

Comment: @MartinR my bad, flagging a question will automatically mark as a "close", I should add it manually. Also, you're right about it; It *could* be -somehow- related...

Comment: Unless you have custom functionality that requires you to implement a custom solution, see if you can avoid re-inventing the wheel and reference or use one of the libraries below: https://github.com/mnbayan/AutocompleteTextfieldSwift https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField

Comment: [Comparing strings with tolerance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344320/comparing-strings-with-tolerance). Or implement your own algorithm, it shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: You can have an idea there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412710/how-to-searchpredicate-content-from-list-like-xcode-suggestion/44413753#44413753

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44412710/5215474 doesn't working it matches me wrong cells. That code is not acceptable. Also i need to have swift version please do reopen the question @MartinR

Comment: Did you try both answers that I linked to? Please provide a *concrete* example if it does not work for you.

Comment: @MartinR Im using swift

Comment: Then *why* did you tag the question with both [objective-c] and [swift] originally?

Comment: Thats by mistake i have changed it just after getting objective c answers

Comment: " doesn't working it matches me wrong cells." My code works last time I checked. It's a solution similar to the one by @Martin R. The "matches wrong cell" make me clearly think about a bad dataSource implementation.

Comment: Im getting wrong cells in search results. im trying to correct it now. But code i need to have is in swift

Answer (score 1):

```
//Filter within Tableview delegate functions

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", SEARCH_TEXT];
    NSArray *filtered = [arrayCategories filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    return filtered.count
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELLSEARCH"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", SEARCH_TEXT];
    NSArray *filtered = [arrayCategories filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    [cell.textLabel setText:filtered[indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: It's better to FILTER before (and change the array), rather than doing it EACH time in `tableView: numberOfRowsInSection` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
let arr = ["job","smart","hating","eating","luck","cup",]
let charset = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "smarting")
for str in arr
{
    if str.lowercased().rangeOfCharacter(from: charset) != nil
    {
    print(str)
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

smart
hating
eating

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to show results from `array`. You can use `NSPredicate`. You need to add all strings in `array` and take another array for showing filtered results like:

```
//filter content from array:
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText {

    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];
    YOUR_FILTERED_ARRAY = [[YOUR_ARRAY filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate] mutableCopy];

}
```

In case you have array of dictionaries then just replace the filtration line with this one

```
YOUR_FILTERED_ARRAY = [[YOUR_ARRAY filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name contains[c] %@)", searchText]]mutableCopy];
//name is the "key" and search text is the matching value!
```

[REFERENCE](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) for predicate.

[Apple API Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1411033-filteredarrayusingpredicate) for `filteredarrayusingpredicate`.

**SWIFT 3x:**

```
//filter content from array:
func filterContent(forSearchText searchText: String) {
    let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF contains[c] %@", searchText)
    YOUR_FILTERED_ARRAY = YOUR_ARRAY.filter { resultPredicate.evaluate(with: $0) }

}

YOUR_FILTERED_ARRAY = YOUR_ARRAY.filter { NSPredicate(format: "(name contains[c] %@)", searchText).evaluate(with: $0) }
```