# How to highlight UILabel formatted phone number while searching

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring, uilabel

How to highlight `UILabel` with formatted phone number while searching?

**Example:**

A cell is displaying a list of contacts with a number like: +381 60 0000000

If I type 3, I want + and 3 to be highlighted (colored differently)

If I type 38160, I want +381 60 to be highlighted (colored differently).

And so on...

---

The main point of this question is how to color the matching numbers by jumping over white spaces and + sign?

Here is what I've tried so far, but it works only if I remove white spaces and + sign from the label's text value:

```
// Highlighted search for numbers
NSString *phoneString = @"+381 60 0000000";
NSString *searchString = @"38160";
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:phoneString];
NSRange selectedRange = [[string string] rangeOfString:searchString options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
if (selectedRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    [string beginEditing];
    [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:selectedRange];
    [string endEditing];
}
cell.phoneNumberLabel.attributedText = string;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your current code look like?

Comment: I have updated question with my code snippet. @Sh_Khan I know that I'm supposed to use attributedText, but I need logic on how to get range of search string that goes over white spaces

Comment: Why is this tagged Swift when the code in the question is in Objective-C? Please tag your question properly.

Comment: This is **not** Swift code. Did you mean to tag this as a Swift question?

Comment: You can mimic this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412710/how-to-searchpredicate-content-from-list-like-xcode-suggestion/44413753#44413753 Just that instead of putting `.*` between each characters, add the correct pattern to match a space or a plus sign, like `\s?` and `\+?` at start, so that you pattern for the current sample be `\+?3\s?8\s?1\s?6\s?0\s` (or `@"\\+?3\\s?8\\s?1\\s?6\\s?0\\s"` in Objective-C)

Comment: @Larme I will check your reply out and try that solution :) Thx

Comment: Thx @Larme your suggestion works, I have answered my own question with a working code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Larme, I have answered my own question :)

```
// Highlighted search for numbers
NSString *phoneString = @"+381 60 000343";
NSString *firstComponent = @"\\+?"; // Skip a leading + char
NSMutableArray *digits = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self.searchString enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [self.searchString length])
                                     options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                                  usingBlock:^(NSString * _Nullable substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                                      [digits addObject:substring];
                                  }];
NSString *pattern = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", firstComponent, [digits componentsJoinedByString:@"\\s?"]];
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:phoneString];
NSRange selectedRange = [[string string] rangeOfString:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];

if (selectedRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    [string beginEditing];
    [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:selectedRange];
    [string endEditing];
}

cell.phoneNumberLabel.attributedText = string;
```